# Ubercart - Sale approval required before payment

Tags: ubercart

Durpal  6, Ubertcart 6.x-2

We are selling table space to vendors at an upcoming convention. We want to let them apply but wait for admin approval before they can pay. I've been searching for several days but cannot find a solution.

Is there a way to require admin approval of a sale before moving to the payment process?

Edit: I have no way of telling that they are vendors until they purchase a vendor table.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to go about this but I would use Rules & custom Role called **Vendor**. You can specify on Drupal load if a user doesn't have a Vendor role & is loading the **cart/checkout** page. That you can redirect them to your application form with a message prompting them to apply before checkout.

Here's an example rule:

```
{ "rules_check_vendor" : {
    "LABEL" : "Check Vendor",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "test" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
          "match" : "cart\/checkout",
          "operation" : "starts"
        }
      },
      { "NOT user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "In order to become a vendor. Please contact us." } },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "contact" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Shawn, I will not know they are vendors until they've purchased a vendor table.

Comment: The idea is flagging accounts via a role to complete purchase with a redirect to some place to apply (thus, not having to rework to checkout workflow). This assumes you're only selling vendor booths and you're going to have people register accounts before checkout.